# Backbone JS v0.5.3 Simple Setup not Functioning?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

I have a simple backbone app that I am using for testing.  Everything seems to be in place and I am not receiving any JS errors, however I am not getting the content requested from the server to display on the page.

I am trying to append some LIs to a UL.  I am logging to the console the backbone models as well as the JSON form so I can clearly see data is being returned as JSON from the server.

Any thoughts on what I am missing in my (extremely simple) backbone implementation?

Check it out here: http://backbonepeople.apphb.com/

```
AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#people',
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function (eventName) {
        _.each(this.model.models, function (person) {
            console.log(person);
            var view = new PersonView({ model: person });
            $(this.el).append(view.render().el);
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function passed to _.each, `this` is not bound to your view which means `this.el` is not defined. Try

```
_.each(this.model.models, function (person) {
    var view = new PersonView({ model: person });
    $(this.el).append(view.render().el);
}, this);
```

or

```
var self=this;
_.each(this.model.models, function (person) {
    var view = new PersonView({ model: person });
    $(self.el).append(view.render().el);
});
```

By the way, `_.each(this.model.models, function...` could be written `this.model.each(function...`